# It is possible to replace curl in Julia Download with wget?

Tags: julia, wget

By Default Julia uses curl to download files on Linux:

```bash
/usr/bin/env julia
julia> using Downloads
julia> Downloads.download("https://pkg.julialang.org/registries"; verbose=true)
```

It is possible to hint Julia to use wget (also available) instead? I see examples on how to [override Curl parameters here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Downloads.jl), but no mention of other tools.

Thanks!

Reason I ask is because we are experiencing a weird issue with Curl (reproduced on the CLI) but CLI with WGET works as expected.

Comment: It looks like this is calling the `libcurl` API, not literally invoking `curl` on the command line, so `wget` would not be a drop-in replacement. If your `libcurl` implementation is broken, I strongly suggest addressing that problem first, as that's going to bite you several more times down the road if you don't.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the source code and it is not easy to replace:


```
The `Downloads` module exports a function [`download`](@ref), which provides cross-platform, multi-protocol,
in-process download functionality implemented with [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).   It is used
for the `Base.download` function in Julia 1.6 or later.
```

Answer (score 0):

> we are experiencing a weird issue with Curl (reproduced on the CLI)
> but CLI with WGET works as expected.

I never used Julia, but recently I learned that it is reasonably easy to call R function using Julia utilizing [RCall](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/RCall.jl). You might give a try if your organization allow usage of said tool. In this case function of interest is [`download.file`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/download.file) and 3 first arguments of it

- `url` string, URL of file to retrieve
- `destfile` string, desired filename
- `method` string, one of following: internal, wininet, libcurl, wget, curl, auto

default is auto, wininet method is Windows-specific, internal is limited to `file://`, so I recommend you try to use libcurl, wget, curl using R and then if it work as intended calling it using RCall.